# Converting "HelloWorld" WCF Web Service to use https?

Tags: wcf, web-services, https

It's really hard to pick up web services if you're a beginner, not because the concept is hard - it isn't - but because the technology has gone through a lot of twists and turns and googling for help *doesn't* help if all you get back are answers for implementations done slightly differently.

[For example our solution has never had a .svc file or .asmx file though those turn up regularly in answers and our web.config doesn't have any `behavior` or `binding` element, as others seem to have]

We've used a tutorial to set up what I think is termed a "WCF Web Service" running on IIS6. It's working fine.

But we'd like to convert it to use encryption/https.

So we've checked the **Require secure channel** box in IIS:
[image]

Not sure what else to configure in there, but ... anyway, moving on. Next I'd imagine we have to modify our web.config file ... but what and how? Here's what we've got under `system.serviceModel` in our web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So what do we need to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it's hard to be prescriptive without ALL of the code unfortunately, but here's the overview:

You'll want to add those bindings and behaviors into the web.config.

I'd start with a basicHttpBinding, and just make it work like it does currently, but this time you'll be specifying your binding details instead of using defaults.  To "turn off" https, change the Security mode in the bindingConfiguration to None.

You'll have something like this for your WCF service when you are done:

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="webServiceClientBehavior" name="My.Service.ServiceName">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:5803/LSClient"  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" contract="My.Service.IServiceName"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

For the bindingConfiguration:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

For the behaviorConfiguration:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="webServiceClientBehavior">
          <!--For MetaData-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:5802/LSClientMD"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

These will need to be adjusted slightly for your implementation, but that's a basic overview.